# How do I load more than one python object stored in the same DAT file?

Tags: python, object, oop, pickle, dat-protocol

So, I'm still learning how to use pickle, and have a limited knowledge of it. This may be a beginner question...
I created this placeholder class:

```
class Student:

  def __init__(self):
    self.__name = ""
    self.__regNum = 0
    self.__fullTime = True
 
  def getName(self):
    return self.__name
  
  def getRegNum(self):
    return self.__regNum
  
  def getFullTime(self):
    return self.__fullTime
    
  def setName(self,name):
    self.__name = name
  
  def setRegNum(self,num):
    self.__regNum = num
    
  def setFullTime(self,fullTime):
    self.__fullTime = bool(fullTime)
```

I created two test students:

```
student1 = Student()
student1.setName("Joe")
student1.setRegNum(2110)
student1.setFullTime(1)

student2 = Student()
student2.setName("Jess")
student2.setRegNum(5124)
student2.setFullTime(0)

dumpFile = open("student.DAT","wb")
pickle.dump(student1,dumpFile)
pickle.dump(student2,dumpFile)

dumpFile.close()

loadFile = open("student.DAT","rb")
```

- but I don't know how to read both separately after loading the .dat file as separate objects.

I tried to use the `with open("student.dat", 'rb') as input:` that I've seen on the internet, but I have no clue what it does to understand why it's not working. I tried numpy.fromfile but I don't understand the outcome I get, and I've seen people use pandas but I don't know a thing. I can't really understand what the solutions are when I look it up, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to dump a `list of objects` into your `.dat` file and retrieve that later while loading.

```
dumpFile = open("student.DAT","wb")
pickle.dump([student1, student2], dumpFile)
dumpFile.close()

loadFile = open("student.DAT","rb")
data = pickle.load(loadFile)    #data now contains a list of the objects
loadFile.close()
```

Then you can just iterate through `data` to access each object separately.

As with the case of using `with open`, its easy to understand. In simple words, it ensures that you dont have to close your file after use.
For example the same code can be written as:

```
with open("student.DAT","wb") as dumpFile:
    pickle.dump([student1, student2], dumpFile)

with open("student.DAT","rb") as loadFile:
    data = pickle.load(loadFile)
```